# How to draw shapes and lines on a View whenever I want?

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw

By "Whenever I want" I mean I can draw new stuff on it when user clicks a button or some kind of event happened or in the `onCreate`... I found some tutorials and they said that I should create a custom view and override `onDraw`. So I tried the following:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint paint;

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }

    public Paint getPaint () {
        return paint;
    }

    public CanvasView (Context c) {
        super(c);
        paint = new Paint ();
        paint.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth (5);
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super (context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint ();
        paint.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth (5);
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super (context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        paint = new Paint ();
        paint.setColor (Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth (5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas c) {
        canvas = c;
    }
}
```

Maybe I am too naive. I added a field called `canvas` and added a getter. As you can see, in the `onDraw` method I assign the canvas parameter to the field. And then in the `onCreate` method I did this:

```
canvas = (CanvasView)findViewById (R.id.canvas);
canvas.getCanvas ().drawLine (100, 100, 500, 100, canvas.getPaint ());
```

I think what I did is really silly. Anyway, I ran my app and... NPE! I deduce that `canvas.getCanvas()` is null.

So this method doesn't work. What is wrong with my code? If I shouldn't do this, what other views can I use in order to draw stuff on it whenever I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of a solution for this, and it WORKS! I deleted the `Canvas` field in the custom view, together with the `Paint` field. Then I created an interface called `Shape`:

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw (Canvas c);
}
```

And here is the new `CanvasView` class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CanvasView extends View {
    private ArrayList<Shape> shapes;

    public CanvasView (Context c) {
        super(c);
        init ();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super (context, attrs);
        init ();
    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super (context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init ();
    }

    private void init () {
        shapes = new ArrayList<> ();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas c) {
        super.onDraw (c);
        for (Shape s : shapes) {
            s.draw (c);
        }
    }

    public void addShape (Shape s) {
        shapes.add (s);
    }

    public void clear () {
        shapes.clear ();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class has an array list of shapes that it needs to draw. We can implement the draw method like this to draw a line:

```
    canvas.addShape (new Shape () {
        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas c) {
            Paint p = new Paint ();
            p.setColor (Color.BLACK);
            p.setStrokeWidth (5);
            c.drawLine (100, 100, 500, 100, p);
        }
    });
```

I think this is a nice way to do it. It basically use interfaces as a "delegate" to drawing a shape on the canvas. When `onDraw` is called, it draws all the shapes in the `ArrayList` on the `Canvas`. Oh, the beauty of reference types!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> And then in the onCreate method I did this:
>   canvas = (CanvasView)findViewById (R.id.canvas);
>   canvas.getCanvas ().drawLine (100, 100, 500, 100, canvas.getPaint ());

1. You need to do the drawing in `onDraw(...)`. Move `canvas.drawline(...)` to that method.
2. Do `canvas.drawLine(...)` instead of `canvas.getCanvas().drawLine(...)`.
3. You need to initialize your `Paint` instance. Don't do `canvas.getPaint()`. Create a field `mPaint` and init it in the constructor.

For a full working example, see Android Developers, Custom Drawing:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Yeah I know that. But What I am asking is how to draw stuff on a click of a button or another view or in `onCreate` etc.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-touch-interaction--mobile-19202